# What is the right way to deal with environments when using AWS API Gateway+lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, continuous-deployment

Let's assume I want to have 2 stage environments for some REST API - prod and staging, and I'm using lambda+api gateway. How to set it up correctly?

As of my point of view, both environments should use the same Lambda function, but different versions of them. Each environment should use a different configuration (pointing to the different databases, or providing a different set of features flags etc), and the best way to provide a configuration is env variables.

But [stages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/stages.html) in API gateway do not support that, the only what is there, is [stage variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/stage-variables.html), and I cannot figure out, how can I use them to "feed" different configs to the same lambda.

So how is it supposed to be done?

Comment: We tried to use the stages for Gateway API, but IMHO it's require a lot of configuration.
As the solution, we have different cloudformation stacks for prod/test/dev environments.

Comment: I also see the only possibility to have a whole set of gateway+lambda for each env. But I guess it's not how it's supposed to be used, otherwise why would be these stages introduced at all?..

Comment: BTW: as for usage of stage variables you could check the following article: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-stage-variables-to-manage-lambda-functions/

Comment: And you know that a lot of AWS services overlap the functionality of each other. I would suppose that the staging for gateway API was initially implemented, but it is hard to work with it. So, I would say that the best and common practice is to split the environments to different stacks.

Comment: I found the article about comparison single stack vs multi stack - https://medium.com/hackernoon/managing-multi-environment-serverless-architecture-using-aws-an-investigation-6cd6501d261e

Answer (score 0):

You can specify [Lambda version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-versions.html) with [aliases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-aliases.html) in its ARN when you set it in API Gateway. For example:

- staging - `arn:aws:lambda:aws-region:acct-id:function:helloworld:$LATEST`
- prod - `arn:aws:lambda:aws-region:acct-id:function:helloworld:stable`

And use these ARNs for different stages in [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-stage-variables-to-manage-lambda-functions/).

Also, in general, for different stages it worth having separate accounts in an [AWS Organization](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/announcing-aws-organizations-centrally-manage-multiple-aws-accounts/) and deploy similar or same CloudFormation stack to these accounts in your integration pipeline.

Comment: I've figured out how to specify different versions, but they would still have the same configuration, wouldn't they? And different configuration is the main differentiation for stages for me. As I understand, it's not really possible, and the only way to archive it - is to have different versions (dev and prod) for API Gateway. But in this case I don't get what the point of these stages at all